# Not able to insert records into database with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, ado.net

I want to insert records in my database with asp.net, but it is not really working out well. The data types of the colums in my database are all varchars, except for the randomID. But I still get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'Inserted text is here'.'

This is my code

```
public partial class Registratie : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Danesh\Desktop\Workshop\App_Data\Stap1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
    int RandomID = 2;
    String Notification = "Uw Identificatienummer is: ";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        RandomID = rnd.Next(1, 10000000);
    }

    protected void BtnStap1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = " insert into Gebruiker values('" + RandomID + "', '" + Voornaamtxt.Text + "', '" + Tussenvoegseltxt.Text + "', '" + Achternaamtxt.Text + "','" + Emailtxt.Text + "' '" + Niveautxt.Text + "' )";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show(RandomID.ToString(), Notification);
        Response.Redirect("/Webpages/LoginPage.aspx");
    }    
}
```

Comment: Google for Bobby Tables. *After* you read it, you'll understand why using string concatenation shouldn't be used to generate SQL statements. One of your text boxes contained the literal text `'Inserted text is here'` resulting in an invalid query. It could be `';Select username,password from Users; --` instead. That's precisely how SQL Injection attacks works. Use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: You are missing comma between emaitxt.text and niveautxt.text

Comment: Do not use `SqlConnection` or anything else that implements [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) as a field. Instead, use a local variable, and wrap it in a using statement.

Comment: Also, this is ASP.NET so do not use MessageBox. That's from Windows Forms, and does not work in a web server scenario.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You Missed Comma(,) in insert Query.

Your Code,

```
 cmd.CommandText = " insert into Gebruiker values('" + RandomID + "', '" + Voornaamtxt.Text + "', '" + Tussenvoegseltxt.Text + "', '" + Achternaamtxt.Text + "','" + Emailtxt.Text + "'(here) '" + Niveautxt.Text + "' )";
```

so try this,

```
cmd.CommandText = " insert into Gebruiker values('" + RandomID + "', '" + Voornaamtxt.Text + "', '" + Tussenvoegseltxt.Text + "', '" + Achternaamtxt.Text + "','" + Emailtxt.Text + "','" + Niveautxt.Text + "' )";
```

Answer (score 2):

Like the comment says, you should parameterise your query to avoid SQL injection, and also in case one the strings the user has typed in contains a special character (escape character or quote).

```
protected void BtnStap1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    var paramsList = new SqlParameter[]
    {
        new SqlParameter("@p1", RandomID),
        new SqlParameter("@p2", Voornaamtxt.Text),
        new SqlParameter("@p3", Tussenvoegseltxt.Text),
        new SqlParameter("@p4", Achternaamtxt.Text),
        new SqlParameter("@p5", string.Join(" ",Emailtxt.Text,Niveautxt.Text),
    };

    cmd.CommandText = "insert into Gebruiker values(@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(paramsList);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show(RandomID.ToString(), Notification);
    Response.Redirect("/Webpages/LoginPage.aspx");
}
```